# What i`m doing wrong ? (python/array declaration)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, syntax-error, declaration

I'm writing this (4 values)

```
clf2 = LogisticRegression()
scores2 = cross_val_score (clf2, X, y, cv=10)
```

...

```
clf5 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=None,
    min_samples_split=5, random_state=0)
scores5 = cross_val_score(clf5, X, y, cv=5)
```

then this

```
class myEnsemble:
    def __init_(self, models):
        self.models = model
    def fit(self, X, y):
        for model in self.models:
            model.fit(X, y)
    def predict (self, X):
        preds = [model. predict(X) for model in self.models]
        res = []
        for i in range(len(X)):
            line = [preds[j][i] for j in range (len(preds))]
            res.append(round(sum(line) / len(line)))
        return res
model = myEnsemble([clf2, clf3, clf4, clf5])
model.fit (X_train, y_train)`
```

But I'm receiving this error

`myEnsemble() takes no arguments`

Why do I have this error

Comment: You're missing a trailing `_` on your `__init__` method.

Answer (score 4):

`__init__` is supposed to have two trailing underscores. You have given only one underscore. So python interprets it as just another regular function and not the constructor. The default constructor is used and therefore it expects 0 arguments. To fix it just add another underscore "_" to the end of `def __init_(self, models):` to make it `def __init__(self, models):`.